# How to solve $(1+x^{2})y'+x^{2}y=e^{\arctan(x)}, y(0)=1$ without using Exponential Integral?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving the ODE, I got it
$$y\cdot e^{x-\arctan(x)}=\int\frac{e^{x}}{1+x^{2}}dx$$

And I saw at WolphramAlpha this integral evaluation arrives in something called Exponential integral.

I don't know how to use is, since I didn't learn complex functions. Is there a way where I could use the fact that $y(0)=1$, without using this Exponential Integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your integrating factor only half way. The differential equation you have equals

$$\left(y' -\frac{1}{1+x^2}y\right) + y = e^{\arctan x} \implies \left(e^{-\arctan x} y\right)' + e^{-\arctan x} y = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

then substitute $v = e^{-\arctan x} y$ to get

$$v' + v = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

The homogeneous solution is $e^{-x}$. To get the particular solution, we will use variation of parameters (i.e. guess that $v_p = u(x)\cdot e^{-x}$)

$$u'(x) = \frac{e^x}{1+x^2} \implies u(x) = \int_0^x \frac{e^t}{1+t^2}dt$$

Then use the initial condition $y(0)=1\implies v(0) = 1$

$$v(0) = 1 = C + 0 \implies C = 1$$

Now substitute back in for $y$ to solve

$$y(x) = e^{-x+\arctan x}\left(1+\int_0^x \frac{e^t}{1+t^2}dt\right)$$

Comment: @Isham you're right, let me fix it.

Comment: What happened to $1+x^2$?

Comment: @mvfs314, I'm sorry it doesn't seem like my answer was able to get around the exponential integral, and no answer will unless you use a power series.

Comment: But how did you find the constant $C$? I don't see any $C$ in the $u(x)$ solution.

Comment: @mvfs314 The $C$ is always a part of the homogeneous solution, not particular.